# How to pause video in AVPlayervewcontroller?

Tags: swift3, ios10, avplayerviewcontroller

I have play video using AVPlayervewcontroller ,but I am facing issue to pause video.
It has a method to stop video than start from beging, but I want to pause video.

Please give me some ideas how can I achieve this?
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

An AVPlayerViewController has an AVPlayer (its `player`). Tell the player to `pause`, or set the player's `rate` to `0`. This pauses the video without resetting its playhead position.

Comment: Can you elaborate I did not get what you say ?

Comment: No, I've said everything there is to say.

Answer (score 0):

[AVplayerviewcontroller](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller) has [`audioPlayer` property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer) which access the the Player Object. To manage the playback, use the `pause` method. Read the full documentation here:- https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1387895-pause

Code example for reference:-

```
  audioPlayer.pause()
```